# Validate Regex with minimum length and new line

Tags: javascript

I am trying to match string having length > 10

```
var value = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and type";
/^.{10,}$/.test(value);
```

returns true;

But, if I have a string with new line character then it fails.

How can i update regular expression to fix that.

I know I can just check .length > 10 or replace new line with space in value. But, i want to update regular expression.

Comment: Why are you insistent on REGEX for this? You've said yourself that there's an easier way

Comment: @Utkanos Same Regular expression in used to validate on server, Where I do not have control. So, I do not want to just fix it in JavaScript by easier way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just length you're testing you should just use `.length`. If you insist in regex, the dot actually matching everything except a newline. You can change this by searching for `\s\S` instead:

`([\s\S]{10,})`

this matches any whitespace and any non whitespace, covering the entire spectrum. Sadly, the `s` modifier is not supported by js regex.

Answer (score 4):

JavaScript does not have a native option for `dot matches newlines`. To get around this, use a different selector:

```
[\S\s]
```

This will match any `Whitespace` or `Non-Whitespace` character.

```
var s = "some\ntext\n",
    r = /^[\S\s]{10,}$/;
console.log(r.test(s));
```

And, the obligatory fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kND83/

There are libraries, such as http://xregexp.com/, that add options for `dot matches newlines`, but all they do is sub in `[\S\s]` for the `.` in your Regex.

Answer (score 1):

`^` and `$` mandate the start and end of a line in the match. Just remove them, and you'll have your answer. Oh, and you need the `m` switch to pass newlines.

```
var r = /.{10,}/m;
r.test(value);
```

Comment: this doesn't work. dot doesn't match new lines. `m` doesn't work either, because dot doesn't match new lines